# Why is this javascript/jquery not capturing user input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't figure out why the user input from the ***search-field*** input box isn't being captured when I go to make a query. When I console log out ***queryURL*** the query from the input box is absent. See my code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>gifTastic!</h1>
        <label for="search-field">Find a TV Show: </label>
        <input type="text" id="search-field">
        <input id="find-giphy" type="submit" value="giphy Search">
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var baseURL = "http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q="
        var apiKey = "Yz4pO4lJDaMYGIX80M9gc2Mq7HKKS2or"
        var input = $("#search-field").val();
        
        var queryURL = baseURL + input + "&api_key=" + apiKey + "&limit=10";

        $("#find-giphy").on("click", function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: queryURL,
                method: "GET"
            }).then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                console.log(queryURL);
            })
        })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is, you are taking value from the input on page load and that value is empty.

You should take the value of the input field inside the click handler function like the following way:

```js
var baseURL = "http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q="
var apiKey = "Yz4pO4lJDaMYGIX80M9gc2Mq7HKKS2or"
$("#find-giphy").on("click", function () {
  var input = $("#search-field").val();
  var queryURL = baseURL + input + "&api_key=" + apiKey + "&limit=10";
  $.ajax({
      url: queryURL,
      method: "GET"
  }).then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
      console.log(queryURL);
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1>gifTastic!</h1>
    <label for="search-field">Find a TV Show: </label>
    <input type="text" id="search-field">
    <input id="find-giphy" type="submit" value="giphy Search">
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to build the query when you *actually* click the button so you can grab the value.

```js
var baseURL = "http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q="
var apiKey = "Yz4pO4lJDaMYGIX80M9gc2Mq7HKKS2or"

$("#find-giphy").on("click", function() {
  var input = $("#search-field").val();
  var queryURL = baseURL + input + "&api_key=" + apiKey + "&limit=10";
  $.ajax({
    url: queryURL,
    method: "GET"
  }).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    console.log(queryURL);
  })
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h1>gifTastic!</h1>
  <label for="search-field">Find a TV Show: </label>
  <input type="text" id="search-field">
  <input id="find-giphy" type="submit" value="giphy Search">
</div>
```